# code example in a javadoc comment

Tags: javadoc

I have multiple programmers contributing examples for javadocs and some examples contain comments formatted with

```
/*
 *
 */
```

When I put these examples into a javadoc comment, the comment close in the example closes the javadoc comment.

```
/**
 *
 * /*
 *  *
 *  */  <-- right here
 *
 */
```

Is there a proper way to handle this without telling everyone that they cannot write comments in this format?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Javadoc comments use html, so encode the / as an entity: `&#47;`

```
/**
 *
 * /*
 *  *
 *  *&#47;  <-- right here
 *
 */
```

Telling everyone not to put that kind of comment in their code examples might be easier.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, if the code is not self-explanatory or at least simple enough to understand with a brief description, then the code should be refactored. It needs to be shorter, or the variables need to be more understandable, or the logic requires rethinking.

In any case, I don't believe there's a way around it, if you wanted to include an example then do not have any comments within that example. If you *really must* have comments, use the // notation.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to put commented source code into a comment?

This sounds like there's something wrong with your design if something like that is necessary.

Comment: Displaying example code in your JavaDoc is one possibility, but the inner JavaDoc block should be html-escaped.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is allowed within Javadoc comments. Enclose the code in your comment within `<code>` or `<pre>` elements. For example:

```
/**
 * Outputs "Hello World" to the console.
 *
 * <code>System.out.println("Hello World");</code>
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

"/* */" comments cannot be nested. "//" comments can be, but they're only effective until the end of the line they start on.

Generally speaking, it's not a good thing to be including actual code in the JavaDocs - for one thing, they should be more abstract (the "why" of things instead of the "how").