# How to generate code samples into javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

Recently I have collected lots of api examples for java api(jdk,log4j,etc.), but I've got a problem about inserting the code example into the project's javadoc. People usually use the javadoc and doclet tools to do this, it seems that the source code of the projects maybe changed. For example [an example](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/survivant/archive/2009/11/08/extends-javadoc-custom-tags-example) , if I want to add an example to Button, then I may have to add an @example tag in the comment of the Button class...

Is there any tool or way can help me to solve this? to generate javadoc with a lot of collected examples from the Internet,without changing the source code too much~ Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I find [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109494/code-example-in-a-javadoc-comment) . It related to your question. But I agree with Michael Barth. So, why would you want to put commented source code into a comment? Сomments and source code should complement each other.

Comment: Thanks for you advice~ but I just want to insert code example into javadoc, not the source code, Is there any automatic way to solve this problem(I have collected quite a lot examples)